# Is General Relativity (GR) compatible with the expanding Earth hypothesis?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, planets, geophysics, aether

There is a lot of convincing evidence that the Earth and all the other planets and their moons are expanding with time.

[Prof. Samuel Warren Carey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Warren_Carey)'s summary of the evidence:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Othb0xsvZb4

The following simulations were made by the graphic artist/designer, [Neal Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neal_Adams), using the surface map transformation principles laid out by Sam Carey, James Maxlow and others:

- [Earth is expanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1oza6jybOA)
- [Mars is expanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=d44Jj_3gp-M)
- [Moon is expanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6_9bldsaxA)
- [Europa is expanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy3_sWF7tv4)

These observations are readily compatible with an [aether-sink theory of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_explanations_of_gravitation#Static_pressure), the mechanism of gravity that Newton suggested in the [Queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queries) (20-22):

**Is General Relativity (GR) compatible with the [expanding Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_Earth) hypothesis, or can it be easily modified to accommodate this hypothesis?**

Please note that a new concept is being proposed here: ***All gravitating bodies expand in size over time***, and the question is: ***can GR safely accommodate and explain this*** or ***a different theory of gravity is necessitated, if the gravitation-implies-expansion hypothesis is proved beyond doubt by observations?***

Answer (score 2):

The expanding earth hypothesis is not sensitive to the subtle differences between different theories of gravity in weak gravitational fields, so yes GR is compatible. However, please be aware that the expanding earth hypothesis is largely considered to be refuted in favor of standard plate tectonics.

Comment: [Wegener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Wegener#Continental_drift_theory) theorized Continental-Drift in 1912, but it was not until the 1950s that this theory was accepted and subduction plate tectonics was formulated. Standard (subduction) plate tectonics and a constant sized Earth implies the Pacific ocean must be a fraction of its actual size. Please see Prof. Sam Carey's video linked above. It is only a matter of time before subduction tectonics gives way to expansion tectonics.

Comment: @Engr. Ravi said “It is only a matter of time before subduction tectonics gives way to expansion tectonics”. And when that time arrives I will revise my answer to reflect the prevailing mainstream scientific consensus of the time.